# Router Issue in React Js (component for showing)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am new to ReactJs  and I want to navigate to another component on button click. I just want to perform a simple routing. This is the code that I tried. But I am not able to route it.

in App.js

```
        import React from 'react';
        import DepartmentShow from './Components/Departments/DepartmentShow';
        import {BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
          <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to = '/departments'>Departments</Link>
    <Switch>
<Route path='/customers' component= {CustomerList} exact={true} />
      <Route path='/customers/new' component= {AddCustomer} />
      <Route path='/customers/edit/:id' component= {EditCustomer} />
      <Route path='/customers/:id' component= {CustomerShow} />
       <Route Path='/departments' component={ListDepartment} exact={true}/>
          <Route exact Path='/departments/:id' component={DepartmentShow} />
     </Switch>
         </BrowserRouter>
```

ListDepartment.js

```
<ul>
              {
                  props.department.map((dept)=>{
                  return <li key={dept._id}><Link to={`/departments/${dept._id}`}>{dept.name}</Link>
                  <button onClick={()=>{handleRemove(dept._id)}}>remove</button>
                  <Link to={`/departments/${dept._id}`}><button>Show</button></Link>
                  </li>

                  })
              }
          </ul>
```

Note: cuustomer component i can route but not department.. :(

DepartmentShow.js

import React from 'react'

```
function DepartmentShow (props){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Show Details</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DepartmentShow
```

When i click on show button my show component should show.
[image]

when i click on show i get url like http://localhost:3000/departments/5e922d889b38110016837a77

but its is not routing to show component.

Comment: Ahm...the code? =)

Comment: @AdrianPascu added...

Comment: So, the url changes, but the component doesn't?

Comment: yes! url changes but component remains same

Comment: Try adding strict to the routes

Comment: tried,, no use..

Comment: Change Path prop to lowercase path

Comment: @PatrykBuniX thnx :)

Comment: I'm glad to help you!